# Express JS - Odd behavior with setting cookies server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

Im banging my head against the wall right now. I do not understand why cookies are behaving so weird.

I am trying to send a response header back to the client with a sessionId cookie.
If i POST /login the cookie will not set but if I make a random endpoint with GET/setCookie it works just fine. Anyone know why this would be happening

```
This does not work
-------------------
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
 var username = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;
 var userID;
​
  db.collection('users')
    .find({username: username})
    .then((userObj) => {
      if(!userObj) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Invalid Username/password" })
      } else {
        console.log("b")
        userID = userObj[0]._id;
        return Utils.comparePassword(userObj[0].password, password)
      }
    })
    .then((isValidPassword) => {
      if(!isValidPassword) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Invalid username/Password" })
      } else {
        return db.collection('sessions')
          .insert({ id: userID, sessionId: Utils.createSessionId() })
      }
    })
    .then((userObj) => {
      console.log("cookie?")
      res.cookie('sessionId', userObj.sessionId, { path: '/' }).send("cookie set")
      // res.set({'Set-Cookie':'sessionId=' + userObj.sessionId, path: '/'})
    })
})
---------------
But this works
---------------
app.get('/setCookie', function(req, res) {
  res.cookie('testCookie', 'test', { path: '/' })
  res.end();
})
app.post('/setCookie', function(req, res) {
  res.cookie('testCookie', 'test', { path: '/' })
  res.end();
})
```

Comment: I assume that `userObj` is valid at the time `res.cookie()` is called?

Comment: Yes, userObj: { id: 5786d27da69f97782cc1cfd4, sessionId: '4f34846a07b8-4724-81b4-1f42f3008eb2', _id:578906f5882830e43bd63d98 }

Comment: And you're not seeing a `Set-Cookie` header in the response?

Comment: Accessing the website and logging in I do not. If I make the post request through Postman I do